# How do I disable shipping in invoice from paypal api V2

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm making an application to send invoices via Paypal's REST API (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/) but I cannot seem to find a way to disable shipping, is this possible to do?

I have tried to mess with "shipping_preference" and tried to find an answer, but I cannot seem to find any information about this.

Comment: I'm glad you asked this question. I have been looking for this also for several days. It seems to be required to put objects in the amount (object) > breakdown > shipping > amount or the API call will fail. When I am able to create an invoice, the response has a 'category_type' of 'shippable'.  I don't want a 'Shipping' line on the invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Through much trial and error, I found a solution to hide ***Shipping*** in the emailed invoice. This solution indirectly changes the (unconfigurable) `category_code` in the invoice from '**SHIPPING**' to '**SERVICES**'.

The [Invoicing API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#invoices_create) displays an array for shipping. In all my tests, sending the request with no tax and no shipping arrays, the API response had failed, declaring 'unable to parse'. Note that the below does not contain shipping.

In the (required) `amount` group of the API request, having the info below, has now solved this issue.

```
 'amount' => 
 array (
   'breakdown' => 
   array (
     'item_total' => 
     array (
       'currency_code' => 'USD',
       'value' => '14.00',          // <- calculate
     ),
     'discount' => 
     array (
       'invoice_discount' => 
       array (
         'amount' => 
         array (
           'currency_code' => 'USD',
           'value' => '0.00',       // <- calculate (for invoice)
         ),
       ),
       'item_discount' => 
       array (
         'currency_code' => 'USD',
         'value' => '0.00',         // <- calculate (for each item)
       ),
     ),
     'tax_total' => 
     array (
       'currency_code' => 'USD',
       'value' => '0.00',           // <- calculate
     ),
   ),
   'currency_code' => 'USD',
   'value' => '14.00',              // <- calculate 
 ),
```